# Why are many links on SuttaCentral showing page not found error?

Tags: texts

Namo Budhhaya. I had bookmarked many Suttas from SuttaCentral but most of them are showing page not found error.
For example : This [link](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn10) and this [link](https://suttacentral.net/en/an2.19).
I wonder why are many links on SuttaCentral showing page not found error?

Comment: They have reorganized the site: [SuttaCentral 2018](https://suttacentral.net/a-new-beginning).
For example MN 10 can now be found here: https://suttacentral.net/mn10 ... the new structure supports having more than one English-language translation of a sutta.
I don't know about AN 2.19. The top-level "index" page with all the AN suttas is here: https://suttacentral.net/an ...

Comment: what I don't really understand about it is that the numbering or sequence of these suttas doesn't match https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/an/ whose introduction says that numbering of "suttas in the Ones and Twos" "are particularly problematic".
More genrally, IMO ideally they might implement [HTTP 301 redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) so they they would transparently continue to support their old URLs, but maybe they can't do everything. Your question might be better posted on https://discourse.suttacentral.net/

Comment: [This post](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/report-bugs-for-the-new-site-here-bug/8605/16) says, "Yes, we are aware of this bug. We are working on it to fix it asap.", so maybe it will be fixed soon.

Comment: The old web site is still available at https://legacy.suttacentral.net/ (though perhaps only temporarily), so for example [this link](https://legacy.suttacentral.net/en/mn10) and [this link](https://legacy.suttacentral.net/en/an2.19) are working at the moment.